# How to use a single UI for two projects in QT?

Tags: python, c++, qt, ros

I need a small help. I have two projects in QT,one a publisher having mainwindow.cpp,main.cpp,mainwindow.ui,qnode and other a subscriber with the same number of files. i want to combine the two .ui files together or lets just say create a new .ui with two tabs each one accessing the publisher.ui and subscriber.ui. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `QStackedWidget`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

Simply add some `QPushButton` instances that can be checkable, and use those as your "tabs".  You can use the `QStackedWidget` index property quite easily with both `QWidget` UIs and QML UIs

Comment: Won't be there any problem if both the projects have the same class name ? And how can i make my push button to link to the other project's UI?